Automate bibtex and pdflatex with TeXstudio
I'm referring to an older question here (but unfortunately I do not have the rights to comment or answer it to bring it up in thread again, therefore I'm posting a new question).
So, I followed Thomas' advice there to automate the execution of pdflatex and bibtex commands, as you can see here in the screenshot:

Unfortunately, it is not working: if I compile afterwards, it still only compiles one round of pdflatex and not pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex as I have configured it. However, the configuration seems stored correctly (when I reopen the Configure TeXstudio menu it is still there). Why is TeXstudio not doing want I told it to do?
Thx for any help!
EDIT:
OK, here is a minimal example showing the problem:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum \cite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

The Log file gives three messages

Package babel Error: Unknown option `greek'. Either you misspelled it(babel) or the language definition file greek.ldf was not found. \ProcessOptions*
Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.

After removing the "greek" option in the babel package everything worked perfectly!

how do you start the compilation?

I just click on compile (or press the shortcut F6)...

it works for me, did you quit both the dialog and the options dialog by clicking on OK?

Yes, I even restarted the program and computer...

@PhilippStrasberg Are there any magic comments at the start of your .tex file which might overwrite these settings?

Indeed, it worked with a minimal example, but it does not work in my TeX file (see my edit in the question)! Now, the question is which of the many packages/options makes it fail to work? Very strange, would not have thought this could be the cause...

@PhilippStrasberg Can you show a full example? In case there are error in the tex file, this could prevent bibtex from creating the bibliography.

Indeed, it works now after removing "\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}" (this also returned an error about "unknown option greek"). I probably ignored it because the pdf nevertheless compiled and I do not get an error when using Kile on Ubuntu. But it caused an error with TeXstudio on Linux Mint. So, many thanks for spotting this!!! Now, of course, I would like to know why this is the problem and why Kile on Ubuntu does not have it...

Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

As a starting point, you could edit your question to include a small test file which allows us to reproduce the problem and show the corresponding .log file. Maybe you need to install the necessary packages for greek...

I did. Many thanks for the help. Perhaps it was simply that the new computer did not have the greek option installed...

Try to install this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-greek If you use a vanilla texlive: tlmgr install babel-greek. If you use use some linux package for texlive, you might have to check which of them contains this package.
